# How to get shares count of a facebook post? it's possible to do?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get shares count of a user post or a fan page post ...

I tried something like:

graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID]/?access_token=xxxxxxx

but it doens't returns the share count ...

is there another way to do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this same method to retrieve the share count in my application. The share count is only returned if the post has been shared. If the post hasn't been shared, then the share count is not returned.

If you only want to retrieve the share count and not the entire post object, then use `https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]_[POST_ID]?fields=shares`

The Facebook API returns the following:

```
"shares": {
    "count": 252
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work anymore. Looks like FQL link_stat is the way to go atm.

Comment: and FQL does not work today. Facebook API sucks. With experimentation over the course of a month, with a variety of token types, the above variably works for each of the different types of tokens.